# python pandas stop fillna at last non NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a dataframe where the index is date increasing and the columns are observations of variables. The array is sparse.
My goal is to propogate forward in time a known value to fill NaN but I want to stop at the last non-NaN value as that last value signifies the "death" of the variable.

e.g. for the dataset

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | NaN | 11 | NaN |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2020-03-01 | NaN | NaN | 14 |
| 2020-04-01 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 2020-05-01 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2020-06-01 | NaN | NaN | 15 |
| 2020-07-01 | 3 | NaN | NaN |
| 2020-08-01 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

I want to output

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | NaN | 11 | NaN |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | NaN | 14 |
| 2020-04-01 | 2 | NaN | 14 |
| 2020-05-01 | 2 | NaN | 14 |
| 2020-06-01 | 2 | NaN | 15 |
| 2020-07-01 | 3 | NaN | NaN |
| 2020-08-01 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

I can identify the index of the last observation using `df.notna()[::-1].idxmax()` but can't figure out how to use this as a way to limit the `fillna` function

I'd be grateful for any suggestions. Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for forward filling by mask - testing only non missing values by back filling them:

```
df = df.where(df.bfill().isna(), df.ffill())
print (df)
              a     b     c
2020-01-01  NaN  11.0   NaN
2020-02-01  1.0   NaN   NaN
2020-03-01  1.0   NaN  14.0
2020-04-01  2.0   NaN  14.0
2020-05-01  2.0   NaN  14.0
2020-06-01  2.0   NaN  15.0
2020-07-01  3.0   NaN   NaN
2020-08-01  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Your solution should be used too if compare Series converted to numpy array with broadcasting:

```
mask = df.notna()[::-1].idxmax().to_numpy() < df.index.to_numpy()[:, None]
df = df.where(mask, df.ffill())
print (df)
              a     b     c
2020-01-01  NaN  11.0   NaN
2020-02-01  1.0   NaN   NaN
2020-03-01  1.0   NaN  14.0
2020-04-01  2.0   NaN  14.0
2020-05-01  2.0   NaN  14.0
2020-06-01  2.0   NaN  15.0
2020-07-01  3.0   NaN   NaN
2020-08-01  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: thanks both @jezrael and @sophods - Ive taken this answer as for my dataset (3500 x 2000) it is quicker than the `.apply` approach: 400ms vs 1500ms - thanks both

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Series.last_valid_index` which is specifically designed for this (to return the index for last non-NA/null value) , to just `ffill` up to that point:

Assuming your dataset is called `df`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[:x.last_valid_index()].ffill())

       index    a     b     c
0 2020-01-01  NaN 11.00   NaN
1 2020-02-01 1.00   NaN   NaN
2 2020-03-01 1.00   NaN 14.00
3 2020-04-01 2.00   NaN 14.00
4 2020-05-01 2.00   NaN 14.00
5 2020-06-01 2.00   NaN 15.00
6 2020-07-01 3.00   NaN   NaN
7 2020-08-01  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

More on this on:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html

Comment: thanks both sophods and @jezrael - Ive taken this answer as for my dataset (3500 x 2000) it is quicker than the .apply approach: 400ms vs 1500ms - thanks both